# A problem on vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider $k$ vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and answer the three questions in cases of $k < n, k = n, $ and $ k > n$:

(i) Are the vectors linearly independent?

(ii) Do they span $\Bbb{R}^n$?

(iii) Do they form a basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$?

I think the answer will be $k\leq n$. But in book answer is $k>n$ and inconclusive for $k\leq n$. I am surprised after watching this answer. How is it possible? As I know If a vector space has dimension $n$. then it has $n$ or less than $n$ linearly independent vectors if it has $n+1$ vectors then it would be linearly dependent.
Am I missing something?
Help me out to solve (i) problem.

Comment: The answer should be nine "yes" or "no" as far as I understand. Please state more clearly your problem.

Comment: "$k$ vectors in an"?? What is "an"?

Comment: @Gerry @ Sorry! I edited.

Comment: maybe, maybe, no; no, maybe, maybe; no, maybe, no.

Answer (score 1):

If $k > n$ then definitely they are linearly dependent, as the largest linearly independent set of an $n$ dimensional vector space has size $n$ ( definition of basis)

If $k \leq n$, then we cannot immediately make any comment without knowing the exact vectors. This is because the vectors can still be linearly dependent. Take for example a 3 dimensional vector space with two vectors, $(1,2,3) , (2,4,6)$

Here, $k=2, n=3$, but the vectors are linearly dependent - but for the case of $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ they are linearly independent with same k,n

Comment: "If $k>n$ then definitely they are linearly dependent" What about $(1,2,3)(2,4,6)(3,6,9)(4,8,12)$?

Comment: @dhanvi : Answer is yes if '$k>n$' for (i).

Comment: @cr001 they are linearly dependent

Comment: The answer is wrong then @Joseph

Comment: @Dhanvi: I think so.